# Fourier synthesis of periodic signals

Tags: fourier-series, transformation, signal-processing

I was reading the [Fourier synthesis of periodic signals](http://www.chem.uoa.gr/applets/AppletFourier/Appl_Fourier2.html)

But I didn't understand the sentence i.e. "Although  the calculation of $a_0, a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2$,  is a mathematically straightforward process, **it may become rather tedious depending on the complexity and the discontinuities of $f(x)$**

> 1. So can anybody explain about what is mean by **discontinuities** in the $f(x)$ ?
> 2. Also, how Fourier synthesis takes care of **factors like different phase values  , different amplitude values and different frequency values of sinusoidal signals** ?

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 1):

> factors like different phase values

$A\sin x +B\cos x = C \sin (x+\phi)$

Or complex coefficients for $e^{i\omega t}$ convention

> different amplitude values

Fourier transform/series are a linear transformation. You can multiply the series by a constant and its transform (forward or reverse) will be multiplied by the same constant.

> different frequency values

$a_0$ refers to constant ($0$ frequency)
$a_1$ refers to component with frequency equal to original signal's period
$a_5$ refers to component with frequency equal to original signal's period/5

> discontinuities in the f(x)"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon

Other than that, it is not complicated at all.

Comment: sir, will you explain it for example given in the question?

Comment: explain what?__

Comment: how will you represent above signal using sum of sinusoidal signals? you can take any amplitude values.

Comment: I can't just look at a signal with my eyes and and tell you the answer...

Comment: sir i have added new signal waveform now.Please go through it.

Comment: why down voted?